# Log system for NodeJS Framework

Tags: node.js, logging

I've created a little pretty framework I use frequently when building NodeJS Web Service but I'm facing a little problem I hope you'll help me to resolve.

Being a Java Dev for years, I'm used to Slf4J (http://www.slf4j.org/)

I can use an interface to define some error/info/warning logs. Users of my frameworks can now decide which implementation they want to use and which level of logs from my framework is needed.

Going back to Node, I have absolutely no idea how to do it.

Is there a way to just define logs and let the framework users choose their implementation and which levels they want to logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bunyan they have log leveling,

```
log.info
log.error
log.warning
```

Comment: Of course... But if I put Bunyan in my framework and... let's say my friend prefer to use Winston, I'll force him to use Bunyan... That's not what I want, I want an agnostic solution like SL4J in Java.